# Is there any way to turn an iPad screen off? (and not put it to sleep)

Tags: ipad, screen

I specifically I want to turn the screen off but have it continue to run whatever app is running, in my case Duet, so that I don't have to restart the app every time I wake the iPad, which I what I currently need to do with the sleep button.

Any ideas would be great. Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that you have to restart Duet if the iPad goes to sleep? Sounds like something the developer should fix.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any way to turn an iPad screen off? (and not put it to sleep)

No. The way iOS is architectured, turning off iPad screen transitions the app to an inactive state. Only if your app supports iOS Background mode execution, can it continue to run.

> I want to turn the screen off but have it continue to run whatever app is running.

Only the apps that support background execution, such as music playback or VoIP calling can continue execution with the screen sleeping.

Answer (score 1):

My easy work around.

1. Place iPad on a table.
2. Take photo, [Photo will be black].
3. Go to photos and click to select black photo.
4. Click [again] on selected photo.

That's all. Enjoy!
Your audio will run with a black screen.
It will look "near black" in a dark room.
Be sure to adjust brightness of the Ipad to darkest setting.

Comment: A black screen does not use less power than a white one. (Brightness setting aside.)